# Why do we need external sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, virtual-memory, external-sorting

The main reason for external sort is that the data may be larger than the main memory we have.However,we are using virtual memory now, and the virtual memory will take care of swapping between main memory and disk.Why do we need to have external sort then?

Comment: virtual memory not being limitless would be one thing I guess

Comment: Does this relate to sorting things on Tape drives? I hear knuth has alot to say about that.
Your tapedrive could be a lot bigger than your hard drive (and thus maximum  virtual memory.)

Comment: @Oxinabox iirc 32-bit Windows machines have a 16TB limit on virtual memory? would need to double-check it.

Second option would be OSs that don't support VM. Thirdly some processes might have the VM they can use limited by the admin etc.

Comment: A random memory access in real memory takes nanoseconds. A random disk seek on a hard disk takes milliseconds. When we were actually using virtual memory, programs with bad access patterns that caused loads of disk seeks took so long it looked like they had failed. What is really happening these days is that physical memories are so big that for almost all problem sizes once data is read off disk it stays in caches on physical memory and never has to be read from it again.

Comment: Mass storage with mechanical devices with highly non-uniform access time is becoming a thing of the past - think terabytes decimeters away, and zetabytes about 100 kilometers.

Comment: *Mass storage with mechanical devices with highly non-uniform access time is becoming a thing of the past*  Damn straight, true in 1975, true in 2015.

Answer (score 7):

An external sort algorithm makes sorting large amounts of data efficient (even when the data does not fit into physical RAM).

While using an in-memory sorting algorithm and virtual memory satisfies the functional requirements for an external sort (that is, it will sort the data), it fails to achieve the non-functional requirement of being efficient. A good external sort minimises the amount of data read and written to external storage (and historically also seek times), and a general-purpose virtual memory implementation on top of a sort algorithm not designed for this will not be competitive with an algorithm designed to minimise IO.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Anonymous's answer that external sort is better optimized for less disk IO, sometimes using in-memory sort and using the virtual memory is infeasible, since the virtual memory space is smaller than the file's size.

For example, if you have a 32 bits system (there are still a lot of these), and you want to sort a 20 GB file, 32bits system allow you to have 2^32 ~= 4GB virtual addresses, but the file you are trying to sort cannot fit in.

This used to be a real issue when 64 bits systems were still not very common, and is still an issue today for old 32 bits systems and some embadded devices.

---

However, even for 64 bits system, as expained in previous answers, the external sort algorithm is more optimized for the nature of sorting, and will require significantly less disk IO than letting the OS "take care of things".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows, in common line shell, you could run "systeminfo", it gives me my laptop's memory usage information.

```
Total Physical Memory:     8,082 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,536 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  11,410 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 2,686 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    8,724 MB
```

I just write a app to test **max size** of array I could initialize from my laptop.

```
public static void BurnMemory()
{
    for(var i = 1; i <= 1024; i++)
    {
        long size = 1 << i;
        long t = 4 * size / (1 << 30);
        try
        {
            // 1 int32 takes 32 bit(4 byte) memmory, 
            var arr = new int[size];

            Console.WriteLine("Test pass initialize a array with size = 2^" + i.ToString());
        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryException err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reach memory limitation when initialize a array with size = 2^{0} int32 = 4 x {1}B= {2}TB",i, size, t );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems it terminate when it is trying to initialize array with size of 2^29.

```
Reach memory limitation when initialize a array with size = 2^29 int32 = 4 x 536870912B= 2TB
```

What I get from the test:

- It is not hard to reach the memory limitation.
- We need to understand our server's capability, then decide whether use in-memory sort or external sort.